# Error building partial dependence plots for RF using FinalModel output from caret's train() function

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret, one-hot-encoding, k-fold

I am using the following code to fit and test a random forest classification model:

```
> control <- trainControl(method='repeatedcv', 
+                         number=5,repeats = 3, 
+                         search='grid') 
> tunegrid <- expand.grid(.mtry = (1:12)) 
> rf_gridsearch <- train(y = river$stat_bino,
+                        x = river[,colnames(river) != "stat_bino"], 
+                              data = river,
+                              method = 'rf',
+                              metric = 'Accuracy',
+                              ntree = 600,
+                              importance = TRUE,
+                              tuneGrid = tunegrid, trControl = control)
```

Note, I am using

```
train(y = river$stat_bino, x = river[,colnames(river) != "stat_bino"],...
rather than: train(stat_bino ~ .,...
```

so that my categorical variables will not be turned into dummy variables.
solution here: [variable encoding in K-fold validation of random forest using package 'caret'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64495561/variable-encoding-in-k-fold-validation-of-random-forest-using-package-caret))

I would like to extract the FinalModel and use it to make partial dependence plots for my variables (using code below), but I get an error message and don't know how to fix it.

```
> model1 <- rf_gridsearch$finalModel
> library(pdp)
> partial(model1, pred.var = "MAXCL", type = "classification", which.class = "1", plot =TRUE)
Error in eval(stats::getCall(object)$data) : 
  ..1 used in an incorrect context, no ... to look in
```

Thanks for any solutions here!

Comment: in `partial(model1,...` add `train = river`) The function tries to extract the training data from the fitted model object which in this case (when fitted via caret) does not contain it. So you msut provide the training data to pdp as mentioned in this tutorial https://bgreenwell.github.io/pdp/articles/pdp.html.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I didn't have much luck using that tutorial (I am a bit new to R in general), but I suppose simply running the same model with 'randomForest' and then using this output instead for the pdps should produce the same result.